# How to open a image matching a field

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have to create a database with more than ten thousand records. There is a field on which image by clicking the image to be displayed with the default program based on the image on which you clicked. Whit this code:

```
Private Sub Campo1_Click()

Dim L As Long

L = ShellExecute(0, "Open", """" & "C:\Users\Nick\Desktop\Documenti\Pictures\DioDiego.jpg" & """", vbNullString, vbNullString, 1)

End Sub
```

when onClick event happens on the image is displayed the same image regardless of the record on which you clicked. How do I change the code to open the image of the field that was clicked? (I'm a beginner of VBA)

Answer (score 0):

With this "C:\Users\Nick\Desktop\Documenti\Pictures\DioDiego.jpg" you are telling to your application to open the ***DioDiego.jpg*** as you have hardcoded in the command. Try giving the the image-file-name to the end of the path depending on which image the user clicks on.